# Client host rejected: cannot find your hostname + SMTP

Tags: email, smtp, centos, vps, exim

I have a VPS configured with exam. Now for some of the mails that I send are rejected with the following error:

```
indiaoffice@kare.de
    SMTP error from remote mail server after initial connection:
    host mail-in.m-online.net [212.114.242.11]: 554 5.7.1 Client host
rejected:
    cannot find your hostname, [107.170.134.52]

    SMTP error from remote mail server after initial connection:
    host mail-in.m-online.net [212.114.242.11]: 554 5.7.1 Client host
rejected:
    cannot find your hostname, [107.170.134.52]
```

Comment: Your question was answered yesterday in http://serverfault.com/questions/628840/client-host-rejected-cannot-find-your-hostname-smtp

Answer (score 0):

I think that mx-servers rejected your connection on dnscheck like "Host lookup failed for your ip-address", which has back record (PTR) and hasn't direct record for host  webserver1.corporatepixels.com

```
~> host 107.170.134.52
52.134.170.107.IN-ADDR.ARPA domain name pointer webserver1.corporatepixels.com
~> host webserver1.corporatepixels.com
Host not found.
```